# Images are not fit in android react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a splash screen that displays an image at the center. The image is perfectly visible and fit in iphone. But in android the image is cropped and some portion from top and bottom is not seen.

```
const win = Dimensions.get('window');
const ratio = win.width / 817;

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.logoContainer}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                    source={require('../../../assets/logo.png')}
                />
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0d2c4f',
    justifyContent: 'center'
},
logoContainer: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
},
logo: {
    width: win.width,
    height: 123 * ratio,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
}
});
```

Why the images are different in iphone and android, is there anything else to be done in my code. How to fix the image in android. Really need help.

Comment: What happens if you just set `logo` to have `width: '100%'` and `height: '100%'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Platform`

```js
const win = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Dimensions.get('window') : Dimensions.get('screen')
resizeMode={'contain'}
...
logo: {
    width: win.width,
    height: 123 * ratio
```

Comment: @JithinVarghese  Could you try this? my updated code

Comment: I have replaced `Text` with `View` and `width:'100%'`. Now it is works. Thanks for the help.